# Using find with 2 sets of variables

Tags: bash, find, variable

I want to be able to run a find command in my  bash script that will find files based on two separate variables. I've gotten this far but I'm not sure how to get the final result working

```
find . -user $userid -name $filename
```

Here is the file of parameters I want to use:

```
cat $uidscript  
10017:title  
10001:options.php  
10005:dump.php(235)
```

So on so forth, the variable contains the username and the file owned by the username.

I think I need to separate the userid and the filename into two separate lists.

```
userid=$(cat $uidscript|cut -c1 -d':')
filename=$(cat $uidscript|cut -c2 -d':')`
```

From here I'm not sure how to organise the find command into a `for` loop. I would think it would go something like this..

```
for i in $userid, $filename;
do 
    find . -user $userid -name $filename; 
done
```

Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `while-read` loop to process the lines of the file

```
while IFS=: read userid filename
do
    find . -user "$userid" -name "$filename"
done < "$uidscript"
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other options are fine, I'd like to correct some mistakes in your approach:

`userid=$(cat $uidscript|cut -c1 -d':')`:

- `-c` gets characters, you need *fields*. Use `cut -f1 -d:`.
- Useless use of cat: Just do: `cut -f1 -d: <"$uidscript"`.
- Store the result in an array so you can iterate over it and another array easily:

  ```
  IFS=$'\n'  # split on newline
  set -f     # disable the glob part of the split+glob operator
  userid=($(cut -f1 -d: <"$uidscript"))
  ```
- Same for the filenames.

Then you can loop over the indices of either array:

```
for i in "${!userid[@]}"
do 
    find . -user "${userid[i]}" -name "${filename[i]}"; 
done
```

Comment: @Stephane That's odd. I tested out that before posting (and added a space to an entry just to be sure), and I got three lines as expected. `bash -c 'userid=("$(cut -f1 -d":"<blah)"); for i in "${!userid[@]}"; do echo "${userid[i]}"; done'` gave me `10017`, `10001 1`, `10005` on separate lines. The parent shell is `zsh`, if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
IFS=:   # split on :
set -f  # disable glob part of the split+glob operator
echo find . $(
  awk -F: '
    {
      printf "%s", sep "(:-user:" $1 ":-name:" $2 ":):"
      sep = "-o:"
    }' < "$uidfile")
```

(remove the `echo` if that's the right command you want to run).